# Stored procedure returning 0 records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The following stored procedure has been created. I have researched online to find out why when I call the stored procedure, I get 0 rows affected when there should be rows.

```
DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sgr_leena`.`test` $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `sgr_leena`.`test` ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE id char(36);
    DECLARE parent_id char(36);
    DECLARE ird_number nvarchar(20);

UPDATE sgr_leena.tasks 
     SET parent_id = @parent_id 
     WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_c FROM sgr_leena.accounts_cstm 
     WHERE ird_number_c = @ird_number and
     keeper_c='Keeper');

UPDATE sgr_leena.calls
     SET parent_id = @parent_id 
     WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_c FROM sgr_leena.accounts_cstm 
     WHERE  ird_number_c = @ird_number and
     keeper_c='Keeper');

UPDATE sgr_leena.meetings
     SET parent_id = @parent_id 
     WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_c FROM sgr_leena.accounts_cstm 
     WHERE ird_number_c = @ird_number and
     keeper_c='Keeper');

UPDATE sgr_leena.notes
     SET parent_id = @parent_id 
     WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_c FROM sgr_leena.accounts_cstm 
     WHERE ird_number_c = @ird_number and
     keeper_c='Keeper');

UPDATE sgr_leena.emails
     SET parent_id = @parent_id 
     WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_c FROM sgr_leena.accounts_cstm 
     WHERE ird_number_c = @ird_number and
     keeper_c='Keeper');

UPDATE sgr_leena.accounts_accounts_1_c
     SET accounts_accounts_1accounts_idb = @parent_id 
     WHERE accounts_accounts_1accounts_idb IN (SELECT id_c FROM    sgr_leena.accounts_cstm 
     WHERE ird_number_c = @ird_number and
     keeper_c='Keeper');

UPDATE sgr_leena.accounts_contacts_1_c
     SET accounts_contacts_1accounts_ida = @parent_id 
     WHERE accounts_contacts_1accounts_ida IN (SELECT id_c FROM sgr_leena.accounts_cstm 
     WHERE ird_number_c = @ird_number and
     keeper_c='Keeper');

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The stored procedure call I am using  call `sgr_leena`.`test`

I have researched using IN parameter but don't want to call an ird_number when running the stored procedure.

I want to run the stored procedure so it would update the parent id's with the keeper id based on IRD number.

Comment: Hi Ken thanks for you feedback not used to being on here asking questions any advice you could give will be greatly appreciate. I am new to asking questions on here and will get the hang eventually.

Comment: Anyone else out there who could help I would be greatly appreciated for help and support